# Java JFrame: how to prevent deletion of text after launching application

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield

Dear fellow Stackoverflowers,

How does one prevent deletion of text after launching the application?

I can't seem to get setEditable(false); to work, any help on that?

Or are there any non-editable alternatives to setText?

Thank you for your time and help.

Much appreciated!

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.text.TableView.TableRow;

public class KitchenView extends JFrame {

  private JPanel contentPane;
  private JTable table;

  /**
   * Launch the application.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        try {
          WaiterView frame = new WaiterView();
          frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  /**
   * Create the frame.
   */
  public KitchenView() {
    setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 1920, 1080));
    setName("frameKitchenInterface");
    setResizable(false);
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JPanel pnlLogo = new JPanel();
    pnlLogo.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    pnlLogo.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
    pnlLogo.setBounds(41, 32, 311, 74);
    pnlLogo.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 20));
    contentPane.add(pnlLogo);
    pnlLogo.setLayout(null);

    JTextArea txtrRestaurantNameAnd = new JTextArea();
    txtrRestaurantNameAnd.setBounds(57, 25, 196, 22);
    txtrRestaurantNameAnd.setText("Restaurant Name and Logo");
    pnlLogo.add(txtrRestaurantNameAnd);

    // table = new JTable();
    TableColumn column = null;
    TableRow row = null;

    JTable table = new JTable(10, 5);
    table.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    table.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));

    table.setRowHeight(32);

    // configure column 0
    table.setValueAt("Menu Item", 0, 0);
    column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
    column.setMinWidth(10);
    column.setMaxWidth(1000);
    column.setPreferredWidth(1000);

    // configure column 1
    table.setValueAt("Quantity", 0, 1);
    column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
    column.setMinWidth(10);
    column.setMaxWidth(1000);
    column.setPreferredWidth(60);

    // configure column 2
    table.setValueAt("Status", 0, 2);
    column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
    column.setMinWidth(10);
    column.setMaxWidth(1000);
    column.setPreferredWidth(100);

    // configure column 3
    table.setValueAt("Time Placed", 0, 3);
    column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
    column.setMinWidth(10);
    column.setMaxWidth(1000);
    column.setPreferredWidth(100);

    // configure column 4
    table.setValueAt("Paid", 0, 4);
    column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);
    column.setMinWidth(10);
    column.setMaxWidth(1000);
    column.setPreferredWidth(50);

    table.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    table.setBounds(41, 675, 1341, 320);
    contentPane.add(table);

    JPanel pnlClientCalls = new JPanel();
    pnlClientCalls.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    pnlClientCalls.setBounds(41, 154, 311, 440);
    contentPane.add(pnlClientCalls);

    // Client Calls List
    DefaultListModel model;
    model = new DefaultListModel();
    JList listClientCalls = new JList(model);
    listClientCalls.setBorder(new LineBorder(UIManager.getColor("Button.shadow")));
    listClientCalls.setBounds(1, 1, 307, 444);
    pnlClientCalls.add(listClientCalls);

    model.addElement("Element1");
    pnlClientCalls.setLayout(null);

    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(listClientCalls);
    pane.setBounds(1, 1, 307, 389);
    JButton addButton = new JButton("Take Order");
    addButton.setBounds(1, 392, 154, 46);
    JButton removeButton = new JButton("Complete Order");
    removeButton.setBounds(155, 392, 154, 46);

    pnlClientCalls.add(pane);
    pnlClientCalls.add(addButton);
    pnlClientCalls.add(removeButton);

    JTextArea txtrClientCalls = new JTextArea();
    txtrClientCalls.setBounds(41, 117, 124, 26);
    contentPane.add(txtrClientCalls);
    txtrClientCalls.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("CheckBox.background"));
    txtrClientCalls.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    txtrClientCalls.setText("Client Calls");

    JTextArea txtrTable = new JTextArea();
    txtrTable.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    txtrTable.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("CheckBox.background"));
    txtrTable.setText("Table: ");
    txtrTable.setBounds(41, 638, 66, 26);
    contentPane.add(txtrTable);

    JLabel lblTable = new JLabel("____");
    lblTable.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    lblTable.setBounds(133, 635, 42, 28);
    contentPane.add(lblTable);

    // Pending Calls List
    JTextArea txtrPendingCallsTo = new JTextArea();
    txtrPendingCallsTo.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("CheckBox.background"));
    txtrPendingCallsTo.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    txtrPendingCallsTo.setText("Pending Calls to other Waiters");
    txtrPendingCallsTo.setBounds(456, 120, 220, 23);
    contentPane.add(txtrPendingCallsTo);

    JPanel pnlPendingCalls = new JPanel();
    pnlPendingCalls.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
    pnlPendingCalls.setBounds(454, 154, 311, 440);
    contentPane.add(pnlPendingCalls);
    pnlPendingCalls.setLayout(null);

    DefaultListModel model1;
    model1 = new DefaultListModel();
    JList listPendingCalls = new JList(model1);
    listPendingCalls.setBorder(new LineBorder(UIManager.getColor("Button.shadow")));
    listPendingCalls.setBounds(0, 0, 311, 440);
    pnlPendingCalls.add(listPendingCalls);
    model1.addElement("Element2");

    // Ready for Collection List
    JPanel pnlReadyCollection = new JPanel();
    pnlReadyCollection.setBounds(882, 154, 212, 440);
    contentPane.add(pnlReadyCollection);
    pnlReadyCollection.setLayout(null);

    DefaultListModel model2;
    model2 = new DefaultListModel();
    JList listReadyCollection = new JList(model2);
    listReadyCollection.setBorder(new LineBorder(UIManager.getColor("Button.shadow")));
    listReadyCollection.setBounds(0, 0, 212, 440);
    pnlReadyCollection.add(listReadyCollection);
    model2.addElement("Element3");

    JTextArea txtrReadyForCollection = new JTextArea();
    txtrReadyForCollection.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("CheckBox.background"));
    txtrReadyForCollection.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    txtrReadyForCollection.setText("Ready for Collection");
    txtrReadyForCollection.setBounds(882, 118, 151, 25);
    contentPane.add(txtrReadyForCollection);

  }
}
```

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: I suggest you have a look at [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) and [the accompanying documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) as they will help provide you with the information you need to find your solution

Comment: Have a look at [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html), [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) and [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) when you want to know why your scroll bars aren't appearing around your `JList` or `JTable` (or `JTextArea`)

Comment: Apparently I did WaiterView instead of KitchenView LOL